# Permissions error when trying to share file via Intent.EXTRA_STREAM

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting the following exception when trying to share a file with Intent.EXTRA_STREAM:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://... requires the
> provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

I have my fileprovider setup as:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

The file share works fine, however I noticed the exception in the log, I have read that this is possibly an issue with access to clipdata.

There is really nothing I can show about the file as its binary so I have tried to create my own clip data to resolve the issue:

```
val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(Intent().apply {
   action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
   putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
   type = "application/octet-stream"
   clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Label", "Text")
}, null)

shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

However this still results in the same exception in the logs.

I have also use ShareCompat.IntentBuilder() to create the share intent and the same exception is thrown.

Lastly tried:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
   clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Label", "Text")
   putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
   type = "application/octet-stream"
   addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}

share(Intent.createChooser(intent, null))
```

1. Any ideas on why this exception is thrown when providing ClipData?
2. Can I provide my own ClipData for better UI/UX in the share screen, like perhaps a custom icon or image?

Comment: `am getting the following exception when trying to share a file` Ok. But why didnt you post the used code?

Comment: `share works fine to another app` Another? Which app? And with which app you have te exception?

Comment: You dont have to use clip data at sharing a file.

Comment: `android:exported="false"` Is that provider exported in this way?

Comment: @blackapps What I meant was the actual share works, the exception is shown in the logs but does not affect the share of the file.  Code is there, what are you referencing?  Manifest code is posted, so yeah exported is false and grantUriPermission is true.  I fully understand that I don't need clip data to share, however I believe that the lack of clip data is why the exception is in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `ShareCompat` snippet, which I use without any issues:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
    .addStream(fileUri)
    .setType("*/*")
    .startChooser()
```

When sharing with the `Intent.createChooser` method, set the clip data like this:

```
shareIntent.clipData = ClipData(
  "description",
  arrayOf("*/*"),
  ClipData.Item(fileUri)
)
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..")
```

Also, this method requires you to set `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `shareIntent`.